# Negating a slice in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say that I have an array something like:

```
foo = np.random.rand(2, 5)
```

and I've been given a slice like `[:, [2, 4]]`. What I'd like to do is to efficiently be able to delete the slice out of the array, so basically leaving me with:

```
foo[:, [0, 1, 3]]
```

Here `foo` could be an arbitrary rank tensor with the slice in each dimension being either a `:` or a list of non-repeating positive indices. Is there an efficient way of implementing this without using `np.delete` and a complicated (slow) loop?

Comment: What if col-0 is same col-2? How would you trace it back without having those indices -2,4?

Comment: Right. I stated the question to be a bit more general than I actually need (in case there would have been a generic solution), but I see that arbitrary indexing can choose elements more than once, which makes it hard to interpret what the negation should be. I'll edit the question to reflect what I actually need.

Comment: Do you actually want to delete those elements from the original array, or do you want a view on the array without altering the original?

Comment: I don't need the old values, so whatever is the most efficient as I would keep repeating these operations in a loop possibly thousands of times.

Comment: If you receive the actual column numbers as input, you can do this manually: `foo[:, sorted(set(range(foo.shape[1])) - set([2, 4]))]`. If your slice is an actual array of values, as Divakar states this problem is ambiguous.

Comment: What I meant was what if foo[:,0] is same as foo[:,2]. How would you know that the  given slice to be deleted has col-2 and not col-0?

Comment: I can actually work with @jpp's method here. Having compared it to using `np.delete`, it's much more efficient and seems fast enough for what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an input list of column indices you wish to remove, you can remove these elements from a list of all indices.

Simpler still, you can utilize `set.difference` to remove the necessary columns:

```
foo[:, sorted(set(range(foo.shape[1])) - set([2, 4]))]
```

To select specific rows or columns, you should not need to use `numpy.delete`. As you found, this is inefficient with NumPy.